# Create new unique polygons by splitting existing polygon by intersecting polygon ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, splitting

I have polygon shapefiles for a series of roadways in ArcGIS Pro. I also have intersecting polygons for intersections on these roadways. I am trying to split the roadways by cutting them with the intersection polygons so that I have individual midblock polygon segments.

I have been utilizing the clipping tool to achieve this and while visually it appears to work, the data remains the same. The midblock polygons remain grouped and unified to their original polygon ID and display the same data in the attribute table, including shape length and size. How can I split these up so that the new polygons have unique ID's and unique data including their shape length and area?

[image]

Comment: If you are saying that if you select 1 row in the attribute table and many "midblock polygons" highlight in the map then you have a multipart feature created by your clipping process. Explore the help file for the tool multipart to single part to explode out the multipart feature into many individual features.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much!